# "Play on another device" function not working with Samsung Allshare

Tags: networking, connection, tv, smart-tv

**Briefly**
I can't get work "Play on another device" function
[image]

**More detailed**

My Samsung TV (which support network) and PC are in the same network.
The problem is, I can play PC contents from TV. But when I try to control TV remotely from Allshare software (PC), it shows TV only as connected device:
[image]

But not as remote player in "players" list

[image]

The result

[image]

Tried to turn off firewall completely, reset router, re-install software. No success. Please help.

BTW. On this link they kinda explained how to do it, but I software doesn' detect the TV as player in my case: http://www.samsung.com/global/allshare/pcsw/quickguide.html

Comment: what are you running this software on? OS might help, as does your network setup

Comment: Windows 7 x64.I remmember that, simply installed software, and it was detected TV as player after first run. But after OS reinstall, I can't get it work

Comment: We can rule out the network most likely. Is upnp enabled ?

Comment: It's upnp enabled only for usb devices

Comment: Is your TV plugged in via USB? also try this http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Enable-or-disable-network-discovery

Comment: no ethernet cable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, for me at least... there is a small update icon in the "Player" section of settings, that made mine work. Silly you have to do that manually though. It's the little circle thingy next to where it says player.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been troubleshooting the same issue.

Under View, click `Player Control Screen Mode`.

It will bring up a window with your television as the player.
Then you have to add content using the 'Plus' sign near lower left corner

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tests I understand that this stupid program picks a random network adapter. In my computer I have 2 LANs, WiFi, VPN, 2 virtual cards installed by VMWare, another one from VirtualBox. Making lots of tests, randomly I could play on TV but the program asked every time to allow some IPs belonging to these extra cards. 
    So I disabled all network connections except the one connected to the TV, restarted AllShare (right click on the icon), and voila!